# Алгоритм на поиск треугольника максимальной площади среди N точек, которые составляют опуклую оболочку

Tags: алгоритм

Можно ли найти этот треугольник за O(N * log N)? Если да, то как?

Comment: [How to find largest triangle in convex hull aside from brute force search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621364)

Comment: За `N^2` есть вменяемый алгоритм. За `NlogN` есть сомнительные результаты. История длится много лет, "сомнительность" результатов показывает что задача сложная.

Comment: Найти можно. Но сложно. Статья с описанием алгоритма: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.11035